# Azure mobile Services and Asp.net identity

Tags: azure, mobile, asp.net-identity

I have an existing Asp.Net app using Asp.net identity. I want to build a mobile application that will leverage Azure mobile service push notifications.
Is it possible Azure Mobile services to use my websites existing asp.net identity for Authentications so that a user who registers on the web site can use the same credentials to retrieve data / notifications via azure mobile services. 
All the examples I have seen so far regarding authentication on Azure Mobile services have used Facebook/Google/Twitter credentials and this doesn't work for my scenario.

thanks